# Issue with limiting characters in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

This is how I am limiting the characters entered in two textFields...

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == textField1 {
            if (textField1.text?.characters.count)! + (string.characters.count - range.length) > 11 {

                return false
            }
            return true
        } else if textField == textField2 {
            if (textField2.text?.characters.count)! + (string.characters.count - range.length) > 15 {

                return false
            }

        }
         return true
    }
```

But the issue is only `textField1` is not allowing to enter more than 11 characters but `textField2` is accepting any number of characters while it should not have allowed to enter more than 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's nothing wrong with your code, you can try following check list:

- Check if textfield 2 outlet is set. You can do it manually or
- you can try adding a `breakpoint` (or print) in you `else if textField == textField2 {}` block
- Also check if `delegate` of `textField2` is set to `self` as well

If control comes to `else if` block then your code must work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't set the delegate in viewDidLoad,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var textField1 :UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField2 :UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        self.textField1.delegate = self
        self.textField2.delegate = self


    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == textField1 {
            if (textField1.text?.characters.count)! + (string.characters.count - range.length) > 11 {

                return false
            }
            return true
        } else if textField == textField2 {
            if (textField2.text?.characters.count)! + (string.characters.count - range.length) > 11 {

                return false
            }

        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I figured out that the delegate was not set for the second textfield...But have given an upvote....:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set textField2's delegate,And I did a test,your code is work!